# Странная ошибка ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

C# UWP Windows 10

Есть такой код:

```
private ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> GroupedTags = new ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>();

private void Refresh()
{
    GroupedTags.Clear();
    foreach (var x in GetGroupedTags())
        GroupedTags.Add(x);
}
```

При любой попытке добавить или удалить элемент коллекции приложение падает, дебаггер VisualStudio ничего не показывает, `catch` не срабатывает. 
Один раз мильком появилась ошибка: что то вроде "... скорее всего указывает на то что память повреждена".

Пробовал запустить приложение на 2 компах и телефоне - результат везде один.

При чем если выполнить операцию `=` то все норм, падает именно на строках:

- `GroupedTags.Add(x);`
- `GroupedTags.Remove(x);`

Comment: Если ошибки о повреждённой памяти — проблема не здесь. У вас в проекте нет нативного кода или P/Invoke?

Comment: @VladD нету. Причем на другой форме, тот же метод, с таким же списком (но с другим классом) работает нормально

Comment: Ну, это ничего не значит, если память реально повреждена, то проблема может проявиться в любой точке, каким бы правильным код в той точке не был.